# AWS Client VPN - restrict access by IP address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-vpn

I am using AWS Client VPN with mutual authentication and I would like to restrict the access to my VPN endpoint(s) by specific user IP addresses. Is this possible ?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/scenario-restrict.html

Comment: The above link may assist you.

Comment: I have tried it already. But it seems that the security group applied to the VPN endpoint can be used only as a reference for other security groups to restrict inbound traffic.
It can not be used for IP whitelisting. For example I have removed all inbound rules in my VPN endpoint security group, but I am still able to connect to VPN and my private resources. So it does not matter what you will have as inbound for the VPN sg - it always allow any inbound traffic.